# ExpressJS Route Async Middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to use a middleware in Express but I can't get it to work I get infinite loading time when I make a request. I searched on stackoverflow but I couldn't find any examples that used an async await middleware stored in a separate file. Can someone point me in the right direction?

isAuthenticated.js

```
const Auth = require('../auth/auth')

const isAuthenticated = async () => {
    return async (request, response, next) => {
        const token = request.cookies.token;
        try {
            const JWTVerify = await Auth.verifyJWTToken(token);
            next()
        } catch (error) {
            response.json({ status: "failed", message: "Authentication failed invalid token" });
            response.end();
        }
    }
}

module.exports = isAuthenticated
```

Server.js

```
const isAuthenticated = require('./middleware/isAuthenticated')

app.post('/some-route', isAuthenticated, async (request, response) => {


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is the definition of your middleware. You are wrapping it inside a function, but you are not calling it. If you pass it like that to express, express will try to call it but the outer function just returns the inner function. The inner function thus never gets called so `next()` never gets called.

```
const isAuthenticated = async (request, response, next) => {
    const token = request.cookies.token;
    try {
        const JWTVerify = await Auth.verifyJWTToken(token);
        next()
    } catch (error) {
        response.json({ status: "failed", message: "Authentication failed invalid token" });
        response.end();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You returning a function, and thus the middleware is not passing the request forward.

Middleware functions are functions that have access to the request object (req), the response object (res), and the next function in the application’s request-response cycle. The next function is a function in the Express router which, when invoked, executes the middleware succeeding the current middleware.

check ---> http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html

```
const Auth = require('../auth/auth')

const isAuthenticated = async  (request, response, next) => {
        const token = request.cookies.token;
        try {
            const JWTVerify = await Auth.verifyJWTToken(token);
            next()
        } catch (error) {
            response.json({ status: "failed", message: "Authentication failed invalid token" });
            response.end();
        }
    }


module.exports = isAuthenticated
```